# Inject dependency to controller called by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, controller

I would like to know if it is possible (if it is, so **how**? :)), to inject a dependency to a controller called by a directive.

I have a controller controller called **MyCtrl**. Here is his signature:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, dataService, aDependency){...}
```

This Controller is usually defined in my route:

```
.segment('myPage', {
                templateUrl: templatesUrl + 'mypage.html',
                resolve: {
                    aDependency: ['$q', 'dataService', '$location', function ($q, dataService, $location) {
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        dataService.retrieveCCData(defer, $location);
                        return defer.promise;
                    }],
                },
                controller: 'MyCtrl'
            })
```

But now, I would also like to call this controller from a directive.
Problem is that I don't know How to inject the ***aDependency***.
It said that the provider is unknown.
Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('gettingStarted1', ['dataService', function (dataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: templatesUrl + 'mypage.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        //resolve: {
            //datasources: ['dataService', function (dataService) {
                //return null;
            //}]
        //}
    };
}]);
```

Resolve is impossible in directive.
Some help will be appreciate
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `aDependency` a separate service.

```
app.provider('aDependency', function () {
    this.$get = ['$q', 'dataService', '$location', function ($q, dataService, $location) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        dataService.retrieveCCData(defer, $location);
        return defer.promise;
    }];
});
```

You can resolve it with

```
            resolve: {
                'aDependency': 'aDependency',
            }
```

or

```
            resolve: ['aDependency'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "separate service"?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the controller Function from the directive

```
.directive("sampledirective", function (dependancy1, dependancy2, ....) {

return {       
        scope: '=',
        controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
          //DO your controller magic here where you got your scope stuff
        }
  }
})
```

One thing i learned it seems the $scope values arent immediatly updated from directive to Controller. If you use objects like

```
   $scope.smth.smth = 'test'
```

It gets updated immediatly else you would need to $apply

Comment: I prefere to re-use the existing controller instead of re-write it.